# Hardness of bounded modular square root of 1

Tags: number-theory, computational-complexity

If we know any square root of 1 modulo N different from 1 and N-1, then we can find a nontrivial factor of N. So to find such a square root has a certain hardness.

In fact, if in general we ask to decide for given numbers a,b,N whether there exists a square root x of a (modulo N) with 0 < x < b, then this is an NP-complete problem, as shown in a paper by Adleman and Manders in 1978. Even if the prime factorization of N is given as part of the input.

How about if for given numbers b and N we ask whether there exists a square root x of 1 (modulo N) for which 1 < x < b ? Is it also NP-complete?

Comment: Considering that making the query with b = N-1 amounts to factoring, this problem is at least as hard as factoring - which itself may well be NP complete. Do you mean to ask if this is so much harder that unlike factoring we can already prove it to be NP complete?

Comment: I should maybe add that if, counter to expectation, factoring is in general an NP-hard problem, then the answer is obviously "yes", since the knowledge of any square root x of 1 (modulo N) with 1 < x < N/2 would reveal a nontrivial factor of N. So the question is whether this problem, of finding a nontrivial square root of 1 subject to a bound, can be shown NP-complete, without assuming that factoring is already NP-hard.